# How to set terminal size in Android adb shell?

Tags: shell, android, console

When I connect to Android using "adb shell" and run certain commands such as "vim" or "mc", they are restricted to a "window" of 25x80 characters. Since I'm connecting from a desktop computer where xterm has a much higher resolution, I'd like to use it.

How do I resize this console window to e.g. 60x156 characters?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is

```
stty rows 60 cols 156
```

A follow-up question is how do I determine the size of my xterm I'm connecting from so that I can pass it to stty automatically (using a script)?

Comment: Great that you found the solution to your own problem. Don't forget to "accept" it when you are able. However, don't include another question; this isn't a discussion forum. You should open a new question. If it's related you can link to this one from the new question.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the android shell to resize automatically to fit the screen size? Similar to the way it's done on other terminals in Unix?

Comment: i tried this, but it said "/system/bin/sh: stty: not found"... does it have to be installed or something?

Comment: Brad: Yes, it should be part of BusyBox.

Comment: For those who dont know BuxyBox: BusyBox is an app. that has a lot of common unix tools "inside" of it - it's particularly designed for embedded systems. To try it install BuxyBox app on your rooted android.

Comment: How make this permanent?

Answer (score 24):

Typing `resize` after connecting to the device works for me:

```
shell@android:/ $ resize
COLUMNS=192;LINES=44;export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: This was `busybox resize` for me.

Answer (score 17):

If you're on a recent release of Android that uses [`mksh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844732/209050) you can simply do:

```
COLUMNS=156
LINES=60
```

Answer (score -1):

Using mksh, I had to run `eval $(resize)`.

The `resize` command outputs the shell commands `COLUMNS=#;LINES=#;export COLUMNS LINES;` to stdout, but it does not actually execute them.  For that, you can use `eval` and put it in your .profile or shell rc file.  While you're in there, you can add an alias for easy resizing after the actual window is resized.

```
$ grep resize ~/.profile
eval $(resize)
alias rsz='eval $(resize)'
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to eval the result. `resize` by itself just works (it does the proper ioctls)

Comment: In my case at that time (8.5 years ago), I had to use eval. I don't know why, but resize alone was not enough. I was just offering this up as a suggestion based on personal experience. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯